# Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child() in my (MessagesAdapter.java:114)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I receive this error when I run my application. It was run without error but when I open my app and react feeling on my msg then application suddenly stop working and show this error ( Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child() )

Here is my code:

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Message> messages;

    final int ITEM_SENT = 1;
    final int ITEM_RECEIVE = 2;

    String senderRoom;
    String receiverRoom;

    public MessagesAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<Message>messages, String senderRoom, String receiverRoom){
        this.context = context;
        this.messages = messages;
        this.senderRoom = senderRoom;
        this.receiverRoom = receiverRoom;


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == ITEM_SENT){

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_send, parent, false);

            return  new SentViewHolder(view);
        } else {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_receive, parent, false);

            return  new ReceiverViewHolder(view);


        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Message message = messages.get(position);
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid().equals(message.getSenderId())){

            return ITEM_SENT;
        } else {

            return ITEM_RECEIVE;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message message = messages .get(position);

        int reactions[] = new int[]{
                R.drawable.like,
                R.drawable.heart,
                R.drawable.smile,
                R.drawable.laughing,
                R.drawable.surprised,
                R.drawable.sad,
                R.drawable.angry,

        };

        ReactionsConfig config = new ReactionsConfigBuilder(context)
                .withReactions(reactions)
                .build();

        ReactionPopup popup = new ReactionPopup(context, config, (pos) -> {
            if (holder.getClass() == SentViewHolder.class) {

                SentViewHolder viewHolder = (SentViewHolder)holder;
                viewHolder.binding.feeling.setImageResource(reactions[pos]);
                viewHolder.binding.feeling.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {

                ReceiverViewHolder viewHolder = (ReceiverViewHolder) holder;
                viewHolder.binding.feeling.setImageResource(reactions[pos]);
                viewHolder.binding.feeling.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }

            message.setFeeling(pos);

            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("chats")
                    .child(senderRoom)             HERE I RECEIVED ERROR
                    .child("messages")
                    .child(message.getMessageId()).setValue(message);

            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("chats")
                    .child(receiverRoom)
                    .child("messages")
                    .child(message.getMessageId()).setValue(message);

            return true; // true is closing popup, false is requesting a new selection
        });

        if (holder.getClass() == SentViewHolder.class) {
            SentViewHolder viewHolder = (SentViewHolder) holder;
            viewHolder.binding.message.setText(message.getMessage());

            if (message.getFeeling() >= 0) {
                message.setFeeling(reactions[(int) message.getFeeling()]);
                viewHolder.binding.feeling.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {

                viewHolder.binding.feeling.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }






             viewHolder.binding.message.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                 @Override
                 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                     popup.onTouch(v, event);
                     return false;
                 }
             });
        } else {

            ReceiverViewHolder viewHolder = (ReceiverViewHolder) holder;
            viewHolder.binding.message.setText(message.getMessage());

            if (message.getFeeling() >= 0) {
                message.setFeeling(reactions[(int) message.getFeeling()]);
                viewHolder.binding.feeling.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {

                viewHolder.binding.feeling.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            viewHolder.binding.message.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    popup.onTouch(v, event);
                    return false;
                }
            });


        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    public class SentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ItemSendBinding binding;
        public SentViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            binding = ItemSendBinding.bind(itemView);
        }
    }

    public class ReceiverViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ItemReceiveBinding binding;


        public ReceiverViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            binding = ItemReceiveBinding.bind(itemView);
        }
    }



}
```